# React Native: Possible UNhandled Promise Rejection: Can't find variable: name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

While trying to make an app that would ask for 3 dates, i've stumbled on a problem :

I have this:

```
onDateChange = (state) => (event, value) => {
    this.setState({
        [state]: name
    });
}
```

that is called by:

```
<DatePicker
    dateMes={this.state.dateMes}
    mode="date"
    placeholder="select date"
    format="DD-MM-YYYY"
    minDate="01-01-1950"
    maxDate="01-01-2050"
    androidMode="spinner"
    showIcon={false}
    onDateChange={this.onDateChange('dateMes')}
/>
```

When loaded, my 3 datepickers are juste filled with the placeholder. When i open them and select a date, nothing will change (as if i never selected a date)

I believe it's not finding how to make the onDateChange work, but I don't know how to make it work

Thanks for the help !

EDIT: Thanks to Chris G, i got a solution. My function now looks like

```
onDateChange = (state) => (event, name) => {
    this.setState({
        [state]: name
    });
}
```

The error disappeared, but the date are not changed with the datepicker.

Comment: In your parameters you have `value` but you're using `name` in your setState call.

Comment: Well that is indeed a rather dumb error.
Although the error doesn't pops anymore, the dates still don't change :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give this some perspective , OnDateChange prop receives a function which act as a callback you are assigning it fine , but when the callback is invoked reference of 'this' has changed and it couldnt find the variables which are bounded by the class

Now in react-native example they have used Arrow function , which lexically bound the scope of 'this' which explains why you could find the class variables because 'this' still refers to component.
Reference : [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Well thanks for the explanation, it is indeed helping me understand how this works. I'm still new to react-native (and js), so I mostly have problems with the syntax. I will read the arrow function page when i have the time ! :)

Comment: sure , you can also use bind function . go through that also , till then to every callback use arrow functions. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I actually only had to go on the DatePicker official github. They have an example, where they do something like :

```
<DatePicker
    date={this.state.dateMes}  //it was dateMes=..., wich just meant nothing
    mode="date"
    placeholder="select date"
    format="DD-MM-YYYY"
    minDate="01-01-1950"
    maxDate="01-01-2050"
    androidMode="spinner"
    showIcon={false}
    onDateChange={(dateMes) => { this.setState({ dateMes: dateMes }); }}
/>
```

Without any function or whatever

And, well, it works. That's all :).

Comment: Just FYI, `(dateMes) => { this.setState({ dateMes: dateMes }); }` is an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

When you have done setState you must clearly define it in the constructor.Try this

```
<DatePicker
date={this.state.dateMes}  //it was dateMes=..., wich just meant nothing
mode="date"
placeholder="select date"
format="DD-MM-YYYY"
minDate="01-01-1950"
maxDate="01-01-2050"
androidMode="spinner"
showIcon={false}
 onDateChange={(date) => {this.setState({date: date})}}/>

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  this.state = {
                date:''

  };
}
```